# Bisection Method In Python

Tags: python

I'm coding the bisection method in Python. I have set a tolerance for the error in my routine. I have two questions:

1. My function should be able to find the root of an arbitrary continuous scalar-valued function.  How do I pass this to `bisection_method` and use it properly?
2. How can I record how many iterations it takes to reach the specified tolerance?

Code:

```
def f(x):
    return(x**2 - 11)

def bisection_method(a, b, tol):
    if f(a)*f(b) > 0:
        #end function, no root.
        print("No root found.")
    else:
        while (b - a)/2.0 > tol:
            midpoint = (a + b)/2.0
            if f(midpoint) == 0:
                return(midpoint) #The midpoint is the x-intercept/root.
            elif f(a)*f(midpoint) < 0: # Increasing but below 0 case
                b = midpoint
            else:
                a = midpoint
        return(midpoint)

answer = bisection_method(-1, 5, 0.0001)
print("Answer:", answer)
```

which gives the following output:

```
Answer: 3.31671142578125
```

Comment: Concerning (1), I don't think your function works in any case, e.g. for `x**2 - 1`, `bisection_method(-2, 2, 1)` would say "No root found", but there are roots -1 and 1.

Comment: @Prune I originally had it in a list form but it messed up the code programming, that's why I did the manual list

Comment: @user123: you have to put some normal text in between to reset the formatting.  You probably saw how I goofed it up.

Comment: @Prune okay I didn't know you had to add text, I will next time! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the function, simply pass the function name as an argument.  I've changed your function's name to `root11` and made it the first argument to the bisection.

For the count ... you *should* have been able to look this up on line.  Just count iterations as you would before you learned the `for` statement.  Return this with the final answer.

Note that I removed your check for an exact answer: you'll find it on the next iteration, anyway.

```
def root11(x):
    return(x**2 - 11)

def bisection_method(f, a, b, tol):
    if f(a)*f(b) > 0:
        #end function, no root.
        print("No root found.")
    else:
        iter = 0
        while (b - a)/2.0 > tol:
            midpoint = (a + b)/2.0

            if f(a)*f(midpoint) < 0: # Increasing but below 0 case
                b = midpoint
            else:
                a = midpoint

            iter += 1
        return(midpoint, iter)

answer, iterations = bisection_method(root11, -1, 5, 0.0001)
print("Answer:", answer, "\nfound in", iterations, "iterations")

import math
answer, iterations = bisection_method(math.cos, 0, 2, 0.0001)
print("Answer:", answer, "\nfound in", iterations, "iterations")
```

Output:

```
Answer: 3.31671142578125 
found in 15 iterations
Answer: 1.5706787109375 
found in 14 iterations
```

Comment: I see what you did there, so that covers the first question I was asked? I was a little confused with the wording

Comment: Yes: note that `f` is now a function parameter -- whatever function name you pass in will become `f` within `bisection_method`.

Comment: if I wanted to change x*2-11 to cosx would I need to import math?

Comment: Yes; you need to have the function available to pass.

Comment: I used import math then return(math.cos(x)) but I am getting an error

Comment: says nontype object is not iterable

Comment: Right.  You have to pass the *function*, not the result of a call.  Also, how did `cos` get into a `return` statement?  `bisection_method` uses the parameter, `f`.  Only the calling program knows the name `cos`, right?

Comment: could you edit that into your post? I am a little confused, I got the right value when I did the polynomial but this trig function is giving me problems

Comment: last question, if I wanted to make my function root11 cosx-sinx on the interval 0,1 how would I do that? trying to do that now but getting some errors. That will be my last question! thanks for all your edits and your patienc, if you could edit that in that would be great

Comment: That's a separate issue (actually, so was the previous one).  Stack Overflow guidelines require a separate posting for a new question.  Also, that's the proper place to format the code I need to see, *after* you've looked up whatever technique you're trying to use.